# Print out List<byte> as a string value

Tags: c#, list, c#-2.0, byte, arrays

I googled and found the statement to convert `byte[]` value to `string` value as this,

```
string myString =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
```

But I defined the variable to `List<byte>`. How can I convert the `List<byte> bMsg` to `byte[] bMsgArrary`?

```
List<byte> bMsg   to byte[]  bMsgArray ?;
```

Or there is other method to convert `List<byte>` value to `string` value. Appreciated for you help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ToArray()` on the list in order to get `myByteArray` and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
byte[] byteMessage =  bMsg.ToArray();
```